# Exponentials in integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, gamma-function

Prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}}{(a+x)^{m+n}}dx= \frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{a^n(a+1)^m\Gamma(m+n)}$$

I tried backtracking using the definition of Gamma function in integral form,but here seems to be two variables involved in the same integral. I wonder if there is any multiplicative property of Gamma integral that lets one multiply two integrals. However instead of backtracking,a solution using simplification of the integral will be really helpful.

Comment: I would start with Beta function

Comment: @YuriyS [is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution). Substitute $x=ay/(1-y)$.